# VBA declare undefined type variable?

Tags: vba

Thanks for reading this.

I'm working on a personal project. I wrote a script that adds Scripting Runtime (to use Dictionary type), then declares a variable such as DictSummary as Scripting.Dictionary. The problem is, VBA does not allow this as it scans the code for error even before running it. When the Scripting Runtime is not added, the 
**Dim DictSummary as Scripting.Dictrionary** yields **"User-defined type not defined"** error.

```
If ReferenceIsAdded("Scripting") = False Then
    If ProjectIsNA Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll"
    End If
Dim DictSummary As Scripting.Dictionary
```

I tried adding a Function that declares, assigns, and returns a variable of Dictionary type, to avoid this error.

```
Public Function AddADict() As Variant
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set AddADict = myDict
End Function
```

Then I get the variable like this

```
Set DictSummary = AddAdict()
```

It does avoid that error but the returned variable is not quite like that, the type of DictSummary is Variant/Object/Dictionary, while it should be Dictionary/Dictionary for that variable to work. I tried On Error Resume Next but it does not help.

Is there a way to avoid that, or is there a way to optionally declare a variable?

Comment: If it is a personal project, why not just add the reference manually? It takes about 10 seconds. If it isn't a personal project, just use late binding `Dim myDict As Object: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. VBA does have some support for conditional compilation, but I don't think that it would help you here.

Comment: How does `Variant/Object/Dictionary` not work?

Comment: @SMeaden Functionally it would work fine -- but it wouldn't hook into Intellisence (which I am guessing makes OP unhappy with this somewhat odd way of late binding).

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the late binding tips, I read it somewhere but don't have sense that it would work here. Also the Variant/Object/Dictionary works fine, I just made stupid code so it appears "not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you protest at the `Variant` because you could define your function to return an `Object`.  Running the sub `TestAddDict` below the variable `objDict` can be seen in the Locals Window to be of type `Object/Dictionary`

```
Option Explicit

Function AddADict() As Object
    Set AddADict = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Function

Sub TestAddADict()
    Dim objDict As Object
    Set objDict = AddADict
End Sub
```

Comment: Holly**** I didn't even think about returning an object, I'm pretty new to this. Thanks anyway, both Variant and Object works.